# Image uploading with other parameters Android

Tags: java, android, file-upload, retrofit2, multipart

I want to upload image on retrofit API with other 5 parameters, I tried all methods listed on stackoverflow but didn't succeed. I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error` and `{"message":"Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0"}` this repsonse from server. I tried this in POSTMAN but API is working fine in it. Can you please tell me where I'm doing wrong.

**Interface Code.**

```
@Multipart
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@POST("uploaddoc")
Call<UploadDocuments> uploadDocuments(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                      @Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

**API call in activity.**

```
private void uploadImage(String imagePath) {
    File file = new File(imagePath);
        
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"));
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

    Map<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap = new HashMap<>();
    requestBodyMap.put("label", RequestBody.create(encryptedLabel, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")));
    requestBodyMap.put("role", RequestBody.create(encryptedRole, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")));
    requestBodyMap.put("userobjid", RequestBody.create(encryptedUserObjId, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")));
    requestBodyMap.put("whichtype", RequestBody.create(encryptedWhichType, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")));
    requestBodyMap.put("gsttype", RequestBody.create(encryptedGstinSpinner, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")));
        
    Call<UploadDocuments> documentsCall = equibiz_api_interface.uploadDocuments(requestBodyMap, body,"Bearer " + AuthToken);
    documentsCall.enqueue(new Callback<UploadDocuments>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<UploadDocuments> call, @NotNull Response<UploadDocuments> response) {
            UploadDocuments uploadDocuments1 = response.body();
            assert uploadDocuments1 != null;
            if(response.isSuccessful())
                Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                try {
                    assert response.errorBody() != null;
                    Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this, response.errorBody().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<UploadDocuments> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
                Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this, "Socket Time out. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Postman Screenshot (Authorization token added into Header part)
[image: Postman uploaddoc api]

Comment: _"I tried this in POSTMAN but API is working fine in it"_ it'd be helpful if you [edit] the question and attach Postman screenshots here. The 500 Internal Server states that you've some problems in server script. So, first, attach the screenshots here and we'll see what's problem.

Comment: @Shashanth I've added it, Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through the Postman screenshot and your code. The code has some problems. Here are the problems and solutions.

1. The field name for the image/file is `documentimages`, not `file`. Change the field name like below.

   ```
   RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"));
   MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("documentimages", file.getName(), requestFile);
                                                               //^^^^^^ NOTICE THE CHANGES HERE
   ```
2. For text fields (the data you send along with file) set MediaTye as `text/plain` instead of `multipart/form-data`. For example,

   ```
   requestBodyMap.put("gsttype", RequestBody.create(encryptedGstinSpinner, MediaType.parse("text/plain")));
   ```

   Like the above shown, you need to change it to other text fields as well.
3. The headers you were using is not correct. If you use `@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})` as content type here, the Retrofit assumes that the data you send from client to server is JSON, not Multipart Form Data. If you get JSON as the response for the uploaded file from the server, then you can do it like below.

   ```
   @Multipart
   @Headers({"Accept: application/json;"})   // <===== CHANGE HEADER TYPE FROM Content-Tye to Accept   
   @POST("uploaddoc")
   Call<UploadDocuments> uploadDocuments(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                  @Header("Authorization") String auth);
   ```

   Check the header part.

If you want to understand more about the headers, refer to this [thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31231)